# Scroll Event Lag/Delay

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues when using a scroll jQuery event to apply toggle a class depending on the users scroll position. Unfortunately, it's causing issues on users browsers where it "lags" or there is a huge delay in the script executing.

Is there a more efficient way to do this which wouldn't cause any issues with lag/delay?

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= 40) {
          $(".main-navigation").addClass("glazeNav");
      } else {
          $(".main-navigation").removeClass("glazeNav");
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: this is perfect, something else on your page causing this problem,

Answer (score 0):

Tried to run your script when the web page is fully loaded

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function ()
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 40) {
       $(".main-navigation").addClass("glazeNav");
    } else {
       $(".main-navigation").removeClass("glazeNav");
    }`enter code here`
   })
  });
</script>
```